# Configuration System Failed to Initialize/Unrecognized configuration section <SectionName>

Tags: .net, frameworks

I debug below code in a newly installed desktop. It is simple to check my environment.
I have searched the error via internet, but no answer can fix my problem. I guess maybe it is caused by file system permission.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string test = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aaa"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(test);
}
```

And App.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aaa" value="bbb" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I got error as below:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section appSettings
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
  at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
  at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue, it is caused by .net framework which is installed incomplete. Please refer to follow link to localize the source of your problem "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration"